# Does the Angular 2 compiler (ngc) work with Typescript definition files?

Tags: angular, uwp, ionic2, typescript2.0, angular2-compiler

Building an Ionic 2 application that targets Windows 10 UWP. Throughout my code, I access the winrt API's directly, like this

`var localStorage = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current.localStorage;`

Compiling with tsc works, but when I compile the application with the ngc, it throws an error `Cannot find namespace 'Windows'`

Obviously, the Angular AOT wouldn't know anything about the winrt Api's because it's not running within the context of a UWP, but I thought that's what Typescript definition files were for.

But how do I work around this issue? I thought that perhaps including the Typescript definition file would have solved this, but Typescript compiles fine.

Here's my projects typings.json file

```
{
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {},
  "globalDependencies": {
    "winrt": "registry:dt/winrt#0.0.0+20160622234326",
    "angular-protractor": "registry:dt/angular-protractor#1.5.0+20160425143459",
    "core-js": "registry:dt/core-js#0.0.0+20160725163759",
    "jasmine": "registry:dt/jasmine#2.2.0+20160621224255",
    "node": "registry:dt/node#6.0.0+20160831021119",
    "selenium-webdriver": "registry:dt/selenium-webdriver#2.44.0+20160317120654"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to make this work. Basically, you manually need to add a reference at the top of your Typescript file, and then compile. Hope this helps someone.

`/// <reference path="../../typings/globals/winrt/index.d.ts" />`